# undo/redo like printio.ru in Fabric.js

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, fabricjs

I want to get Undo/  Redo functionality like `http://printio.ru/`  in My code ,How can i write undo /redo for My canvas .

I tried http://jsfiddle.net/SpgGV/27/ in My code but it doesn't work perfectly , 1 step undo redo will also work .

Any suggestion?

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var hw=[];
var x=0;
var current;
var list = [];
var state = [];
var index = 0;
var index2 = 0;
var action = false;
var refresh = true;
state[0] = JSON.stringify(canvas.toDatalessJSON());
console.log(JSON.stringify(canvas.toDatalessJSON()));
$("#clear").click(function(){
    canvas.clear();
    index=0;
  });
 $("#addtext").click(function(){
   ++index;
   action=true;  
 hw[x] = new fabric.Text('Sample', {
   fontFamily: 'Hoefler Text',
    left: 100,
    top: 100,
    //textAlign: 'center',
    fill: 'navy',

});

canvas.add(hw[x]); 
          x++;
}); 
canvas.on("object:added", function (e) {

    if(action===true){

        var object = e.target;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(canvas.toDatalessJSON()));
    state[index] = JSON.stringify(canvas.toDatalessJSON());
    refresh = true;
        action=false;
        canvas.renderAll();
    }
});
function undo() {

    if (index < 0) {
        index = 0;
        canvas.loadFromJSON(state[index]);
        canvas.renderAll();
        return;
    }


    console.log('undo');

    canvas.loadFromJSON(state[index]);

    console.log(JSON.stringify(canvas.toDatalessJSON()));
    canvas.renderAll();
    action = false;
}

function redo() {

    action = false;
    if (index >= state.length - 1) {
        canvas.loadFromJSON(state[index]);
        canvas.renderAll();
        return;
    }

    console.log('redo');

    canvas.loadFromJSON(state[index]);

    console.log(JSON.stringify(canvas.toDatalessJSON()));
    canvas.renderAll();

    canvas.renderAll();

}

canvas.on("object:modified", function (e) {
    var object = e.target;
    console.log('object:modified');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(canvas.toDatalessJSON()));
    state[++index] = JSON.stringify(canvas.toDatalessJSON());
    action=false;
});

$('#undo').click(function () {
    index--;
    undo();
});
$('#redo').click(function () {
    index++;
    redo();
});
```

Comment: Look into [command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern)

Comment: one way of achieving the undo/redo is to save the entire canvas state in a variable, you may save states on events like move, color change, resize, rotate etc and then just iterate through the json index for state of the canvas. Check the following site letztroll.com for implementation

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25357895/using-stateproperties-and-hasstatechanged-to-implement-undo-redo-in-fabric-js) for a working but unpolished approach.